# Past exam paper question on Reduction of order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Verify that $U_1(x)=x$ is a solution to the differential equation and solve

$$x^2y''-x(x+2)y'+(x+2)y=0$$ Where $x>0$.

> I've done most of the method, i'm at the point where you reduce the problem to a first order system, and then solve by using the separable method. It sounds stupid but i'm not sure what to do with this integral
>
> $\int (1/w) {dw} = \int (1) {dx}$
>
> and what the final answer should be.

Then use the Wronskien to show that the two solutions gained are linearly independent.
(sorry that I couldn't write my entire methodology, i'm not that good with HTML yet).

Comment: As is cited by KittyL the second solution is $u_2=v_1(x)u_1(x)$, see the second paragraph in **An example** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order). By substitution you can compute that the wronskian is distint to zero when $x>0$. The approach of this method is find easily (see the shape of your equation) a first solution, and after use the cited formula. Since the wronskian say to you that you have two linearly independent solutions, you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this integral, use the formula
$$\int \frac{1}{x}\;dx=\ln |x|+C$$
and 
$$\int \frac{1}{x^n}\; dx=\int x^{-n}\; dx=\frac{1}{1-n}x^{1-n}+C.$$

But your computation is not correct. You should check your formula first. This is what you should get
$$\int \frac{1}{w}\; dw=\int dx.$$

With this you can find the second solution is $xe^x$ since $u_2=v_1(x)u_1(x)=xe^x$. The Wronskian of $u_1, u_2$ is
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
u_1&u_2\\
u_1'&u_2'
\end{pmatrix}$$
where "$'$" represents the derivative. You can try from here to see whether you can get the correct solution. Remember as long as you find two linearly independent solutions, they form a general solution.

Comment: Ah, I didn't carry and $x^2$ in my original $y=v_1(x)u_1(x)$ substitution. Well this is embarrassing...

Comment: I've edited the question, thank you.

Comment: @UniStuffz: I am not sure what you are asking then. Both of the two integrals are basic ones. You should be able to easily solve them and find $u$, then $y_2=uy_1$.

Comment: according to my professor the solution of a reduction of order question gives you a solution of the form $y=v_1(x)u_1(x)+v_2(x)u_2(x)$. However after I do the integral, rearrange for my first order equation, I gain the system $\lambda*e^x + \gamma$ which are constants and not functions. I am also asking the question as I do not know how to use the wronskien to prove linear independence.

Comment: @UniStuffz: I am not sure about the form of the solution you wrote. If $u_1$ is the first solution, $v_1u_1$ is the second solution, then the general solution should be $y=c_1u_1(x)+c_2u_1(x)v_1(x)$. I edited my answer.